# High traffic caused by DHCPv6

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, pfsense

We have a medium sized network setup with multiple switches and one firewall (pfsense). 
We now have IPv6 since two months and sometimes can observe, that there is a huge amount of traffic on the firewall (~800MBit/s).
I ran ethdump and it showed up, that the network is spammed by DHCPv6 - Solicit XID packaged (~200k in 1s), that will slow the network or even break it down.

What for I can see is, that I only saw microsoft products (Windows 7, Windows Server 2012 and one Surface Tablet), no Android or Linux-server was involved by now.

Does anybody has similar experiences or any recommendations? I tried to block it in the firewall (IPv6 UDP dest. port 456-457, but it didn't work)

[image: Wireshark Packagecapture]

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this behaviour before. It tends to happen when you set the M (Managed) flag in the RA (Router Advertisement) but have a DHCPv6 server that doesn't provide the client with IA_NA (basically a DHCPv6 server that doesn't assign addresses). The client will go into a loop requesting addresses over and over again.

If you don't assign addresses with DHCPv6 then you should make sure the RA doesn't have the M flag set. If you need the M flag for some clients then it usually helps to rate limit the other clients. They retry immediately when they receive a DHCPv6 advertise that doesn't give them what they want, but they wait for a timeout when they don't receive a response at all.

I don't know why firewalling doesn't work, it should. But remember that the clients will be using multicast to reach the server (group ff02::1:2), so you might need to adjust your filters to take that into account.

Comment: Good point with the managed flag. Unfortunately it is set to unmanaged. But I will try to activate the DHCP Server and see what happens.